# Sequential and Dynamic Number of Ajax Calls in For Loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
var data = [{start_date:20180601,end_date:20180701},{start_date:20180801,end_date:20180901},{start_date:20181001,end_date:20181101},{start_date:20181201,end_date:20190101}];
var requests = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      (function(i, data) {
        requests.push(function() {
          jQuery.ajax({
            url: 'https://reqres.in/api/users?page=1',
            method: 'GET',
            success: function(result) {
              console.log(i); // 0
              requests[i].apply(undefined, []);
            }
          });
        });
        console.log(i); //counts up
      })(i, data);

    };

 requests[0].apply(undefined,[]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I am wondering, how come with this code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  (function(i, data) {
    requests.push(function() {
      jQuery.ajax({
        url: wpApiSettings.root + 'superdooperendpoint/' + apikey + "/" + data[i].start_date + "/" + data[i].end_date,
        method: 'GET',
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
          // Set nonce here
          xhr.setRequestHeader('X-WP-Nonce', wpApiSettings.nonce);
        },
        success: function(result) {
          success_callback({
            start_date: data[i].start_date,
            end_date: data[i].end_date,
            span: data[i].span,
            result: result
          });
          console.log(i); // 0
          requests[i].apply(undefined, []);
        }
      });
    });
    console.log(i); //counts up
  })(i, data);

};
```

When I do the first `console.log()` in the success function it is always `0`, not `undefined`, yet while outside of the success function it counts up in the iterating for loop. How can I get it to count up in the `success` function as well?

Comment: Why not just use `let` instead of `var`, eliminating the need for the IIFE?

Comment: What do you mean by `counts up`? Also, as both are logging `i` add some prefixes/suffixes for better idea

Comment: @NikhilAggarwal Both a logging `i` yes but in the second `console.log()` it iterates counting up `i++` as the for loop dictates, but in the `success` function it stays at `0`.

Comment: So, if  my understanding is correct that you are saying that for an array of length 2. The log shows 3 `0's` and 1 `1`. Is it correct?

Comment: Can you create a snippet for the same?

Comment: @NikhilAggarwal added so you may see the console log keeps doing `0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following paints the updated value of `i`

**Parallel Calls**

```js
var data = [{start_date:20180601,end_date:20180701},{start_date:20180801,end_date:20180901},{start_date:20181001,end_date:20181101},{start_date:20181201,end_date:20190101}];
var requests = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  (function(i, data) {
    requests.push(function() {
      jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'https://reqres.in/api/users?page=1',
        method: 'GET',
        success: function(result) {
          console.log(i);
        }
      });
    });
  })(i, data);

};

for (var i = 0; i < requests.length; i++) {
  requests[i].apply(undefined, []);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Sequential Calls**

```js
var data = [{start_date:20180601,end_date:20180701},{start_date:20180801,end_date:20180901},{start_date:20181001,end_date:20181101},{start_date:20181201,end_date:20190101}];
var requests = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  (function(i, data) {
    requests.push(function() {
      jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'https://reqres.in/api/users?page=1',
        method: 'GET',
        success: function(result) {
          console.log(i);
          i++;
          if(i < requests.length) {
            requests[i].apply(undefined, []);          
          }
        }
      });
    });
  })(i, data);

};

requests[0].apply(undefined, []);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Explanation** - When you iterated over the function, for each function in `requests` array a value of `i` was passed/stored just like an argument. When you invoke the `requests[0]` from outside, on completion of the function, the stored value of `i` i.e. 0 is painted. And then, you again trigger the function stored at `index = 0` i.e. you end up creating an infinite loop. In order to paint the appropriate value, loop over the `requests`array and call the individual function one by one to see the appropriate value of i being logged.

Comment: This is great but it no longer calls the Ajax requests sequentially... :(

Comment: As in the request should run only after the previous one is done, this was the purpose of the `success` callback.

Comment: @SummerDeveloper - It does now. Check the updated answer

Comment: @SummerDeveloper - Glad to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign `i` to a different local variable of the nested function and put the definition of `i` out of the block;

```
let i = 0;

for (; i < 100; i++) {
  ((n) => new Promise(
     (res, rej) => setTimeout(res, 100)
    ).then(() => console.log(i,n))
  )(i);
}
```